# dojo.connect no longer working with forms?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I was using something like this before Dojo 1.8, but now I get a "node not found" error :

```
<form dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
  Search :  
  <input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="searcht" id="searcht">
  <script type="dojo/connect" event="onSubmit" args="evt">
    my_function();
    dojo.stopEvent(evt);
  </script>
</form>
```

I noticed that if I remove the search text box the code is working.
How can I rewrite the above to work with 1.8, and also please be so kind to point me in the right direction to read about this and understand why this is happening.
I should also note that I'm using the same type of code for contentpanes, and the code works fine there.

Thanks,
Noru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **dojo 1.8** `dojo.connect` is `dojo/on`. First you have to load the modules you are going to use and parse the file to transform *dijit* elements.

```
<script>
require([
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button"
], function(parser) {
    parser.parse();
});
</script>
```

Second, declare the *dijit* properties and funcionality inside *html* tags:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="search_form">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="submit" data-dojo-args="evt">
        evt.stopPropagation();
        alert( "my_function()" );            
    </script>     
    <label for="my_textbox">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" id="my_textbox"/>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="my_button" type="submit">   
        Submit     
    </button>
</div>
```

I used a declaratively example inserting *dijit* options inside the *html* code. There is other way using only *javascript*. Take a look in the official documentation: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/index.html

Comment: Thank you @Birei , I found some examples and replaced the dojo.connect with dojo/on, I just don't understand why the script tag must be placed right after the form opening tag, all my previous code has the script tag just before the form closing tag. Is this explained somewhere in the docs ? I just couldn't find it.

Comment: @noru: I don't know the answer. Sorry.